# Choosing a function based on a type in C99

Tags: c

I can choose a function based on a type in C11 with the `_Generic` keyword.

But in C99? How does this work?

> #define floor( arg ) (4)(since C99)
>
> 4. Type-generic macro: If arg has type long double, floorl is called.
>    Otherwise, if arg has integer type or the type double, floor is
>    called. Otherwise, floorf is called.

source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor

Comment: You need to `#include <tgmath.h>` for the functionality described. -- https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.22

Comment: The C99 standard doesn't say how it should work, only that it should work. It is up to the compiler to implement this by whatever magic it has up its sleeve.

Comment: Having a portable way for people to do the same sort of thing as tgmath is *why* `_Generic` was added in C11.

Comment: No. You must use compiler specific extension for it. For example __builtin_choose_expr in GCC